# exec: \"mysql\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I've created a container based on the mysql:5.7 image. Then I set the password with this

`docker run --name mysql -v $(pwd):/src -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:5.7`

Then I deployed my modules using docker-compose up -d on my docker-compose.yml file. Apparently, it raised an

`exec: \"mysql\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown`

error and my 2 other modules also are having errors that keeps on restarting and point to mysql. I can import Python files in Django shell as well as `mysql -u root -p` but I cannot use the imports when it can't connect to the database.

Things I did based on my research:

1. I've set my Windows 10 environment variables to point at
   **C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin** where mysql.exe resides. It still didn't work.
2. mysql-init.txt (REF: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html): This runs the mysql prompt successfully.

   `grant all privileges on *.* to root@localhost;`

   `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  # Mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    hostname: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DB=bitpal
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"


  # Redis
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
    hostname: redis
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"


  # Django web server
  bitpal:
    image: python:3.5
    restart: always
    hostname: bitpal
    container_name: bitpal
    working_dir: /bitpal
    command: ./bin/start_dev.sh
    volumes:
      - ./bitpal:/bitpal
      - ./etc/config:/etc/config
      - ./log:/log
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - mysql
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      # Database
      - DB_NAME=bitpal
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
      - DB_HOST=mysql
      - DB_PORT=3306


  # Celery worker
  worker:
    image: python:3.5
    restart: always
    container_name: worker
    command: bash -c "./bin/install.sh && ./bin/celery_worker.sh"
    working_dir: /bitpal
    volumes:
      - ./bitpal:/bitpal
      - ./etc/config:/etc/config
      - ./log:/log
    links:
      - mysql
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis


  # Bitshares websocket listener
  websocket_listener:
    image: python:3.5
    restart: always
    container_name: websocket_listener
    command: bash -c "./bin/install.sh && ./bin/websocket_listener.sh"
    working_dir: /bitpal
    volumes:
      - ./bitpal:/bitpal
      - ./etc/config:/etc/config
      - ./log:/log
    links:
      - mysql
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis


  # Nginx
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.12.1
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./bitpal:/home/bitpal/bitpal/bitpal
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - bitpal
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.5

RUN mkdir -p /bitpal

WORKDIR /bitpal
EXPOSE 80

ADD requirement.txt /bitpal/
RUN python3.5 -m pip install -r /bitpal/requirement.txt
```

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'bitpal',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': SECRETS['db']['default']['hostname'],
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {'autocommit': SECRETS['db']['default']['commit']}
    }
}
```

**docker version**

```
Client:
 Version:       18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    0520e24
 Built: Wed Mar 21 23:06:28 2018
 OS/Arch:       windows/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.04.0-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.4
  Git commit:   3d479c0
  Built:        Tue Apr 10 18:23:35 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

**docker info**

```
Containers: 6
 Running: 3
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 3
Images: 6
Server Version: 18.04.0-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 46
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.93-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 18.04.0-ce (TCL 8.2.1); HEAD : b8a34c0 - Wed Apr 11 17:00:55 UTC 2018
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 995.6MiB
Name: default
ID: I7DZ:5SQN:EOBV:PJOE:YHNK:RSXK:F6EH:4J7P:LSTI:CR2M:E2MV:VI27
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

**docker inspect mysql:5.7**

```
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:0d16d0a97dd13a8ca0c0e205ce1f31f64d9d32048379eb322749442bff35f144",
        "RepoTags": [
            "mysql:5.7"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "mysql@sha256:f030e84582d939d313fe2ef469b5c65ffd0f7dff3b4b98e6ec9ae2dccd83dcdf"
        ],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2018-05-04T23:41:21.907294662Z",
        "Container": "7fed895363c6e67ba9d52eaea107a1267d63e2d5ad46c567926d6897c7175624",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "7fed895363c6",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "3306/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.7",
                "MYSQL_MAJOR=5.7",
                "MYSQL_VERSION=5.7.22-1debian9"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "CMD [\"mysqld\"]"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:71f4997ae44aead33eefe93100990253bca456f7b63dc5aad5baa936e7c14c46",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/mysql": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": [],
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "DockerVersion": "17.06.2-ce",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "3306/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.7",
                "MYSQL_MAJOR=5.7",
                "MYSQL_VERSION=5.7.22-1debian9"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "mysqld"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:71f4997ae44aead33eefe93100990253bca456f7b63dc5aad5baa936e7c14c46",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/mysql": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": [],
            "Labels": null
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 371961246,
        "VirtualSize": 371961246,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": null,
            "Name": "aufs"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:d626a8ad97a1f9c1f2c4db3814751ada64f60aed927764a3f994fcd88363b659",
                "sha256:0fea3c8895d3871f5c577987f09735ae0889811efbad0dfde4d57851a4d40c00",
                "sha256:ed9fd767a1ff316e1a5896e150cede3ba2bcfe406d2135a6bc6306295cc479af",
                "sha256:f9dfc87a2e756c25245847a95ced53a6c065405b417d7635a28aa88235b30786",
                "sha256:5081cf9eb26642b5373aaa6eea7e16b6caefc3a495cf8fa0f296df48d8651f2f",
                "sha256:0404d129c384e4f45e5ae6a8d89c388a323bc0dda82ea45c6e4d0a442ea1e4b0",
                "sha256:98bb41f25d3307bc5c124529cfde7c3c27a0d612d918e91a36fc1e852e2e629c",
                "sha256:c11f67aad663de23cb77fbbbc6f7bee656e95e72cc820733aed6430a618738ab",
                "sha256:d2f1dc45f8bf45758eee7bc59fe94e9f251c415ef8d08540529d1a004772ee9e",
                "sha256:01df4e5c105921d20d800c1250c66009d472eb5628817bfa2c9523df5c53e03c",
                "sha256:4f840ea0733fe23b9fda79ff521a2e6e8112a615df5db064570502af19c08511"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Please include `docker version`, `docker info`, and `docker inspect mysql:5.7`

Comment: @BMitch post edited. Hope this gets resolved soon. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, I just got it resolved. I had to remove my nginx container then `docker-compose -d up mysql redis`, I then went to create a database `docker exec -ti mysql bash` command then went inside `docker exec -ti bitpal bash` and migrated the DB. Then I restarted the bitpal container and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just got it resolved. Apparently, I forgot to create the DB and migrate the new changes. Here's how I did it.

1. Removed **nginx** module. My **worker** (celery) and **websocket_listener** modules are okay to keep on restarting. `docker rm -f nginx`
2. Ran in detached mode. `docker-compose up -d mysql redis`
3. Used bash under mysql container. `docker exec -ti mysql bash`
4. Entered credentials (I have initially set them in **mysql-init.txt**, REF: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) `mysql -u root -p`
5. Created DB. `CREATE DATABASE bitpal;`
6. Imported a certain .sql file that was missing in my modules.
7. Ran bitpal in detached mode. `docker-compose up -d bitpal`
8. Used bash under bitpal container. `docker exec -ti bitpal bash`
9. Migrations. `python manage.py migrate`
10. Used bash under mysql container. `docker exec -ti mysql bash`
11. Lastly, ran the sql under bitpal container. `mysql -u root -p bitpal < <.sql file>`
12. And it worked.

Comment: I can't see any rational relationship between any of these steps, except maybe step 10, and mysql not being in the PATH. The larger set of instructions might be useful to you, but each Stack Overflow question and its answers should be about **only one** narrow, specific technical problem; steps followed to solve different problems belong to answers attached to different questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best option for the above issue. I did a lot of search for the same issue:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mariadb-server
sudo apt-get install --reinstall php-mysql

service mysql status

service mysql start
```